# Android Menu duplication fixed with clear but it clears the parent activity menu

Tags: android, menu, duplicates

I have created different fragment and populated some menu based on the fragment. I was getting duplicate menu items so I used clear as suggested various stackoveflow posts but the problem is when I use clear in fragment it also clears the main activity menu items.

Comment: Did you fix it? Where was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Activity and all fragments inside it use the same `Menu` instance. So no matter where you call `clear()` method, all items will be deleted.

Menu items that are used across all child fragments should be created inside `Activity`. Fragment-specific options should be created inside corresponding fragment. Ideally you should not have duplicated menu items. If two fragments have same menu item but third doesn't -- prefer create menu item inside every fragment but not single menu item inside activity. With this approach you will not get duplicates.

---

But If you want just to delete duplicates you can use [`menu.removeItem(itemId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#removeItem(int)) method. Also you can hide redundant item with [`menuItem.setVisible(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)).

Comment: Hey Andrew thanks :) Yes, i have created common menu in Main activity which is shared across Fragment. The menu I was getting duplicated are from Fragments. When I  switch between Fragments, I get duplicated menu and those menu items are non reactive. So I have applied menu.clear() in main activity OnCreteOptionMenu() but I am still getting the dupilcate menu when I switch between fragments.

Answer (score 0):

> When I switch between Fragments, I get duplicated menu

Maybe you have two active fragments at the same time. It can be when you use [`add`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add_2) method instead [`replace`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace_1).